# How can one edit the size of the course image?

Tags: image, moodle, lms

I have currently uploaded a course image to go along with the description and the title of the course however the image while it is 720x380p is displaying as a very small image. I Don't understand why.
[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbwYw.png)

Comment: Please check out some other questions on StackOverflow so you see the format. You need to provide some context about what you are doing and show your minimum, complete repeatable code. Also, it's no use providing pictures of images from screen-captures as they are the wrong size, often thewrong type and difficult to work with. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's a theme issue. You can customize the size by modifying the CSS.
If you are using Boost theme go to *Site administration > Appearance > Themes > Boost > Advanced settings*

Then paste in the Raw initial SCSS box the following:

```
.coursebox {
    .content {
        .courseimage {
            img {
                max-width: 200px !important;
                max-height: initial !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To customize the size, change the numeric value in the `max-width: 200px !important;`, above.

Note, you'll be modifying images for all courses.
Also, take into consideration all screen sizes to not break your theme.